# Sending mail not send in java

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send mail in java by this code. but i fail to send email

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String to = "abc@gmail.com";
    String from = "xtz@gmail.com";
    String host = "localhost";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("This is Subject");
        message.setText("This is The  message Body");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
     System.out.println("This is Exception Part >-------->"+ex);
    }
}
```

But i found this Exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179807/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-localhost-port-25-nested-exception-is-java-n

Comment: Are you running an SMTP server on your computer? (If yes, why isn't it listening on port 25? If not, then why are you trying to connect to the SMTP server running on your computer?)

Answer (score 0):

It's very probable that your SMTP server(even running on your computer) is not listening on port 25, so what you want to do is try to connect to a different port, for example 587.

If the port to connect to is not specified in the *Transport* property, then the application will try to connect to port 25 by default.

In order to specify a port different than the default one, you need to add the following code:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
          transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_PORT, SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS, PASSWORD);
          transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
          transport.close();
```

I was facing the same problem and it turned out that the port was set to 26.

Apart from that, as good practice, you should use:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
```

and:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
```

You should try to fix [these common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) to prevent future errors.