# Error while sending Email through Local Server

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

> Could not send email: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set().

```
public function changePassword(){
  if($this->request->is('post')){
    $email->from(['from@domain.com' => 'My Site'])
    ->to('to@domain.com')
    ->subject('About')
    ->send('My message');
  }
}
```

Comment: is your mailserver running on localhost:25?

Comment: yes @jhyot
''EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => true,
        ],
    ],'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179807/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-localhost-port-25-nested-exception-is-java-n)